# How to make dynamically youtube iframe from any youtube url in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, url

I want to make a PHP script that parse ANY youtube link/url and makes an output of iframe that i can later store in SQL database and insert on my site.

Any help appreciated

> **EDIT & ANSWEAR**
>
> 1) get video ID
>
> ```
> $step1=explode('v=', $url);
> $step2 =explode('&',$step1[1]);
> $vedio_id = $step2[0];
> ```
>
> 2) create iframe
>
> ```
> <iframe width="320" height="240" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'. $vedio_id.'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You need a script that will convert a url to an embed code
check this links [URL to Embed Code PHP Script](http://buffernow.com/youtube-url-to-embed-code-generator-php-script/)

with this script you can convert any youtube or vimeo link to embed code and
you dont need to save the embed code in db just save vedio id. :)

Comment: This is the exact thing i was looking for! Thanks!